# Can Marketing Cloud Pull Blog Post Data Via RSS for E-mail Automation?

Tags: email, wordpress

I'm trying to figure out whether to use MailChimp or Marketing Cloud in order to pull data from a blog automatically, in order to send out E-mails automatically whenever a new blog is posted.

The blog is hosted on WordPress, which is in turn really within Magento - a plugin is being used to make WordPress compatible with Magento. This plugin limits our options for E-mail automation, hence RSS.

So can Marketing Cloud create E-mails automatically via RSS? If so, please provide any documentation you can. I can't seem to find it.

Thank you kindly!